# BigInteger in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate query params is causing error

Tags: oracle, jdbctemplate

I am executing a query with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Query parameter CustomerId has type BigInteger like
queryParams.put("CustomerId", request.getCusttomerId());
when query got executed then it throws exception that 'invalid data type is used'.
BigInteger is not allowed ? what are the safe alternatives without losing data

Comment: What is the database type in the database of the `CustomerId` parameter, and what is its intended range? You should use whatever type most closely corresponds to that. `BigInteger` is an arbitrary-precision value, but you probably don't literally need a customer ID that could hold (say) one million digits.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  dataType in database is NUMBER (20)

Comment: That's still awfully big. No "small" type can hold that, but `BigDecimal` should, and it's one of the things supported by `PreparedStatement`, so it has a good chance of working.

Comment: There will be no data loss while converting from BigInteger to BigDecimal ?

Comment: No. `BigDecimal` is basically just `BigInteger` with a decimal point. You do have to take care when going from `BigDecimal` to `BigInteger` (the other way around) since, obviously, `BigInteger` has no decimal point. All that said, you should look at whether customer IDs are really supposed to be 20-digit numbers. A `long` holds up to 18 digits, and while an `int` holds a mere 9, few businesses actually have more than the 2.1 billion customers that would warrant a bigger type. (There are other reasons for using bigger numbers, but `NUMBER(20)` might also just be an unwise default.)

Comment: Okay. I have used BigDecimal noew and query gor executed witout exception.. thank you for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `SqlParameterSource` implementation, and `java.sql.Types`.

```
MapSqlParameterSource queryParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
queryParams.put("CustomerId", request.getCusttomerId(), Types.BIGINT);

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlString, queryParams);
```